# Flutter: AnimationController vsync this issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to implement code from [official docs example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) but it fails:

```dart
...

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this);
  }

...
```

[image]

It says that: `The argument type '_MyHomePageState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider'.`

So, VSCode highlights `vsync: this` param.

I have latest version of Flutter:

```
Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 18116933e7 (6 weeks ago) • 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
Engine • revision d3ea636dc5
Tools • Dart 2.14.4
```

Why this error occurs and how to fix this without downgrading of SDK version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Flutter, an `AnimationController` needs a `TickerProvider`.

When an `AnimationController` is being created from a `State`, you should have the `State` to extend either `TickerProviderStateMixin` or `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`. The latter is more optimized for when you only need to use a single ticker, which should be most of the case.

**Solution for you:**

Change

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
```

into

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I should have been more careful when reading the documentation but debug issue suggesting is not so obvious as it could be. Also many topics for downgrading SDK to solve this issue are confusing too much.